# awk with loops to reorder columns

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to reorder the columns of a file writting a awk programn. The file looks like:

[image]

My little program to reorder the columns is:

```
awk -v column=number 'BEGIN {FS=","; ORS="\n"; OFS=","; n=column} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){if (i!=n)  $(i+1)=$i else $1=$i} {print $0}' file_name
```

I would like to put first the column given with number and then the remaing ones, but it does not work

Comment: `use -v column=$number`

Comment: Replace image by text.

Comment: and add the expected output, also as text.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting fields as you iterate. You should instead "bubble" the value from position in `column` to the first position.

Consider how would you move column 3 here:

```
1 2 3 4
```

to

```
3 1 2 4
```

For example with this input file:

```
$ cat table
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
```

You could do it like this (separators changed to whitespace for readability):

```
$ awk -v col=3 '{val=$col; for (i=col; i>1; i--) $i=$(i-1); $1=val; print $0}' table
3 1 2 4
4 2 3 5
5 3 4 6
6 4 5 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print the required column first and then the rest of columns.

```
$ awk -v column=3 -F "," '{n=column; printf $column; for (i=1; i<NF; i++){if (i!=n) printf ","$i} print ","$NF}' file
```

Input:

```
10,Hello,meow,20,30
hello,world,34,meow,60
```

Output:

```
meow,10,Hello,20,30
34,hello,world,meow,60
```